# How to set rest pose as pose?

Tags: animation

**UPDATE:** Here is the [.blend file](http://pasteall.org/blend/index.php?id=48480)

I would like a step by step guide which shows how I can make it so that the current pose looks EXACTLY like the rest pose.

This is my armature in rest position:

[image]

This is how it looks like in pose position:

[image]

I want to reset the pose position to look like the rest position.

I tried **Pose -> Clear Transform -> All**.

[image]

But this is the result:

[image]

Comment: you probably habe issues with your IK Bones. In Rest Mode (I think) IKs are not calculated

Comment: I don't think so, I followed a professional tutorial.

Comment: I tried everything now, I even copied the original rig from another professional model and same problem. This is most likely a bug.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. In Outliner change to "Current Scene" in dropdown, r/click on
   "metarig" and click "Delete heirarchy". You have two identical rigs
   and meshes, although metarig only shows origins suggesting you
   deleted in edit mode. Irrespective, it messes with your active rig.
2. Select your mesh and apply rotation and scale (ctrl-a).
3. In pose mode select shin.l and delete the Limit Rotation constraint. In the IK panel set the Pole Angle to 0.
4. In pose mode select shin.r and set the pole angle to 0.
5. Ditto forearm.l, set pole angle to 90
6. Ditto forearm.r, set pole angle to -90

edit: formatting

Comment: Thank you very much! I also had to move the pole targets for the arms, but now it looks much more like the rest pose.